# Stream image to file from SavePicker in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I need to save Image from Local Storage Folder to file selected from SavePicker.
Should I use stream?
Here is my code:

```
            StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
            if (null != file)
            {
                var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                StorageFile current_photo = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(img.Tag.ToString());

                // TODO Stream from current_photo to file
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CopyAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227106.aspx) should do it:

```
await current_photo.CopyAndReplaceAsync(file);
```